# left join to count unmatched row gives incorrect count

Tags: mysql

I am using left join to count unmatched rows but although my query is correct i am having some logical problem.
[check this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce409/3)

the query should return count 1 but instead returns 0.I know the reason is because it finds a matched row but i don't know other ways to solve the problem.I need to count the unseen questions by a user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your `qv.question_view_id IS NULL` clause as part of the `JOIN`, not the `WHERE`.

```
SELECT qt.user_id, count(q.question_id) cnt
   FROM questions q 
   INNER JOIN questions_to qt ON qt.question_id = q.question_id
   LEFT JOIN question_view qv ON q.question_id = qv.question_id
   -- Not that I've moved this clause into the JOIN condition.
   AND qv.question_view_id IS NULL 
WHERE qt.user_id = 13
GROUP BY qt.user_id
```